# Pushing an array into another array overwrites all the elements in the second array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm writing a method that modifies an array in a temporary variable and then pushes that variable into a multidimensional array. But when I push the temp variable into the multidimensional array, all the contents get overwritten with the value of temp. This is the method:

```
def possible_moves(start, moves = [])
  return if start.any?(nil)

  temp = []

  # add 2 to first, add 1 to last

  temp << start.first + 2  
  temp << start.last + 1

  moves << temp

  # add 2 to first, subtract 1 to last

  temp.pop 
  temp << start.last - 1

  moves << temp

  moves
end
```

If I run the method with `start = [3, 4]` then the result is

```
moves = [[5, 3], [5, 3]]
```

when the expected result should be

```
moves = [[5, 5], [5, 3]]
```

Also, using `Array#push` instead of `Array#<<` gives the same result.

I'm very new to programming and am having a hard time figuring out what's happening and how to solve it, so any help is very much appreciated. I'm working with Ruby 2.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def possible_moves(start, moves = [])
  return if start.any?(nil)

  temp = []

  # add 2 to first, add 1 to last

  temp << start.first + 2  
  temp << start.last + 1

  moves << [*temp]
  #or moves << temp.dup

  # add 2 to first, subtract 1 to last

  temp.pop 
  temp << start.last - 1

  moves << [*temp]
  #or moves << temp.dup

  moves
end
```

The reason of above behaviour is due to the fact that when you push one array into another then pushed array is not copied , instead it's reference is copied so when you change the source array. Its value in other array changes. Here is a simple illustration to show that

```
ar1 = [1,2,3]
ar2 = [ar1,[5,6]] # [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6]]
ar1[0] = 99
```

now check ar2 , it would be `[[99, 2, 3], [5, 6]]`

You can verify it by checking `object_id` of any ruby object

`ar1.object_id` => somenumber

`ar2[0].object_id` => samenumberagain

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the problem.